# Regarding Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx

I have created a Lightning page with the Tittle "Registration Component" which is calling a child component "Add Education details" with the help of a button named as "+Add Educational Details" in which i have defined a list with the help of controller in which i am storing the number of times usr click on the button:

Lightning Page Code :--

```
 <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >


    <aura:attribute name ="abc" type = "boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name = "NameofStudents" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name = "ParentsName" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name = "StandarodClass" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name = "NoFhourStudy" type="String[]" default=" ,Less Then 1 hour,in between 1 to 4 hrs,
                                                               In between 4 to 8 hrs,More then 8 hrs"/>
    <aura:attribute name = "usersresponse1" type = "string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name = "MobileNumber" type = "Integer" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name = "HaveyoutakencourseBefore"  type = "Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name = "Areyouinterestedinonlinecourse" type ="Boolean" />
    <aura:attribute  name = "CheckBoxValue" type= "Boolean" default= "false"/>
    <aura:attribute  name = "PageHeading" type= "String" default= "Registration Form for the student"/>
    <aura:attribute name="EducationalDetailsList" type="List" default="[]"/>

    <div class="slds-m-top_xx-large">
    <div class="slds-page-header">
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <div class="slds-text-heading--large">

      {!v.PageHeading}    </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    </div>

    <br/> <br/>

    <div class="slds-size_3-of-8">
    <lightning:input label ="Enter Your Name" name="Name" value="{!v.NameofStudents}" />

    <br/> <br/>
    <lightning:input label ="Enter Your Parents Name ?" name="ParentsName" value="{!v.ParentsName}" />
    <br/> <br/>
    <lightning:input label ="Which class do you study ?" name="StandarodClass" value="{!v.StandarodClass}" />
    <br/>

    <lightning:select label ="How many hours do you study ?" name="hrsstudy" value = "{!v.usersresponse1}" >

       <!--   <option value ="red"> 1 </option>
        <option value ="Yellow"> 2 </option>
        <option value ="green"> 3 </option>
        <option value ="blue"> 4 </option>-->



             <aura:iteration items="{!v.NoFhourStudy}" var="hrs">
             <option value="{!hrs}" text="{!hrs}" />

        </aura:iteration>

      </lightning:select>

    <br/>
    <lightning:input type ="telephone" name ="mobilenumber" value ="{!v.MobileNumber}" label= "Enter your Mobile Number"/>

     <aura:iteration items="{!v.EducationalDetailsList}" var="item" indexvar="index">
        <c:Add_Educational_Details EducationDetailsListInnerComponent="{!v.EducationalDetailsList}"/>
     </aura:iteration>


        <br/>     
  <lightning:button iconName="utility:add" variant="border-filled" label="Add Education Details" onclick="{!c.addDetails}"></lightning:button>

     <br/>    
    <lightning:input aura:id ="checkBox" type ="checkbox" onChange= "{!c.onClickCheckBox}" label="Are You available on weekends to take the classes?" name ="firstcheckbox"/>
    <br/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.CheckBoxValue}">
        <br/>
                   <i> Thats great !! Wish You Happy Learning </i>

     </aura:if> 
    <br/>

    <lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.doSubmit}"></lightning:button>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller code as follows :

```
addDetails: function(component,event,helper){

    console.log("Add Educational Details");
    var CurrentEducationdetailsList = component.get("v.EducationDetailsList");
    var currentSize = parseInt((CurrentEducationdetailsList.length));    
    var NewSize = parseInt((currentsize.length) + 1);
    CurrentEducationdetailsList.push(NewSize);
    component.set("v.EducationDetailsList", CurrentEducationdetailsList);
   }
```

Error i am getting on the page as

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Action failed: BispApp56:Registration_Component$controller$addDetails [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]
>   Failing descriptor: {BispApp56:Registration_Component$controller$addDetails}

Please help me with the solution

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to fetch the attribute named `EducationalDetailsList` which you have declared in your component.

But you are fetching that in your controller with a missing **al** in the word *Education* (as  *EducationDetailsList*). And because there does not exist any attribute with that name, hence you are getting error when you are trying to fetch the `length` of an undefined attribute.

Correcting the attribute name in your controller should resolve your issue. The corrected line of code should be as below:

```
var CurrentEducationdetailsList = component.get("v.EducationalDetailsList");
```

Additionally revisit your code for any case sensitivity issues. E.g., you have issue with your `currentSize` variable declaration and usage in the JS controller. You have declared it as `currentSize` and using as `currentsize` (lower s).

Comment: Thanks I have corrected that but still i am getting the error as below                                               Error :- This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: BispApp56:Registration_Component$controller$addDetails [currentsize is not defined]
Failing descriptor: {BispApp56:Registration_Component$controller$addDetails}

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive and that you have defined the variable as `currentSize` and trying to access it using `currentsize`. Few recommendation here -- **1.** Make sure you revisit your code to identify any typo. **2.** Go through some trailhead units around lighting component.  **3.** Limit your question on SFSE to single problem. As in this case you had two different issues. If you keep on editing your original question, your original question may be lost somewhere. However in this scenario, just make the correction and it should work.

Comment: Yaa i got it Thanks for your quick response :) sometimes i do silly mistakes. :(

Comment: Not a problem. We all learn here. And we learn more from our mistakes.